# Passing an SQLiteDatabase delete function a table name as a String in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

If I run:

```
void deleteTableRecords() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_ALBUMS,null,null);
        db.close();
    }
```

I get my intended result. However, if I run:

```
void deleteTableRecords(String tableName) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(tableName,null,null);
        db.close();
    }
```

with a call of `deleteTableRecords("TABLE_ALBUMS")` I get a crash and told that:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: TABLE_ALBUMS
```

What should I be passing a table name as if not a String?

Comment: have you tried this " deleteTableRecords(TABLE_ALBUMS)"?

Comment: do you want to delete the rows in the table or the table itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TABLE_ALBUMS` is the name of your variable. Its value is most probably something else.

I guess you assigned a value to `TABLE_ALBUMS`, for example:

```
private static final String TABLE_ALBUMS = "someValue";
```

In this case you need to pass the actual value, not the name of the variable:

```
deleteTableRecords("someValue");
```

A better approach is to make it a public constant:

```
public class DbHelper {
    public static final String TABLE_ALBUMS = "someValue";

    // ...

}
```

So you can access it in a static way:

```
deleteTableRecords(DbHelper.TABLE_ALBUMS);
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Your explanation reminded me that I had indeed assigned a value elsewhere but had been so used to referring to `TABLE_ALBUMS` for recent code that this idea completely slipped my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the variable in the method not a String.

Assuming you have

```
class DbHelper{
    public static final String TABLE_ALBUMS = "albums";
}
```

Use:

```
deleteTableRecords(DbHelper.TABLE_ALBUMS);
```